# MySQL : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails : 4

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

I got error if I insert  :

```
INSERT INTO klub_pemain (id_klub,id_pemain,tahun_masuk,tahun_keluar,jml_gol) VALUES ('152','aBJAD','1998','2004','50');
```

I write code in visual studio code and source to mysql console

First Table :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS klub;
 CREATE TABLE klub (
 id_klub INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 nama_klub VARCHAR(15),
 tahun_berdiri INT(10),
 direktur VARCHAR(10),
 CONSTRAINT id_klub_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_klub)
 )ENGINE=innoDB;
```

Second Table :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pemain;
CREATE TABLE pemain(
id_pemain INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nama_pemain VARCHAR(10),
tgl_lahir DATE,
kota VARCHAR(10),
CONSTRAINT id_klub_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_pemain)
)ENGINE=innoDB;
```

Third Table :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS klub_pemain;
CREATE TABLE klub_pemain(
id_klub INT(10),
id_pemain INT(10),
tahun_masuk INT(10),
tahun_keluar INT(10),
jml_gol INT(10),
INDEX(id_klub),
INDEX(id_pemain),
CONSTRAINT klub_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_klub) REFERENCES klub(id_klub) ON DELETE 
CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT pemain_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_pemain) REFERENCES pemain(id_pemain) ON 
DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=innoDB;
```

I got message :

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sbd14`.`klub_pemain`, CONSTRAINT `klub_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_klub`) REFERENCES `klub` (`id_klub`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

please help me :( ,, thx :)

Comment: My guess is that one the foreign keys which you mention in your insert statement has no corresponding primary key in either the `klub` or `pemain` tables.  Since you did not post other information, you will have to check this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There I can say two things to you.

1. In your `klub_pemain` table you define all columns data type as
   `INT`, but when you insert data you insert strings. See the values
   of your insert query. `VALUES ('152','aBJAD','1998','2004','50')`
2. The second thing is before you enter data into `klub_pemain`, these referenced data should be in `pemain` and `klub` tables. 
   For example, when you insert `id_klub` as value `152`, this corresponding `152` value row must be in `klub` table.